# Getting error whenever try to replace a column name

Tags: r

Whenever I try to replace column names using the below codes, I get an error.

```
colnames(all_lab_drug)<- str_replace_all(colnames(all_lab_drug),' |-','_')
```

Error

```
Error in str_replace_all(colnames(all_lab_drug), " |-", "_"): 
  could not find function "str_replace_all"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the `stringr` package before running the code.

```
library(stringr)

colnames(all_lab_drug) <- str_replace_all(colnames(all_lab_drug), ' \\|-', '_')
```

Or you can call the package explicitly.

```
stringr::str_replace_all(colnames(all_lab_drug), ' \\|-', '_')

# [1] "drug_one"   "drug_two"   "drug_three"
```

**Data**

```
all_lab_drug <-
  structure(
    list(
      `drug |-one` = c(1, 1),
      `drug |-two` = c(1, 1),
      `drug |-three` = c(1, 1)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-2L)
  )
```